# grouping series of values for correlation computation

Tags: sql, postgresql

with `table1` like below, which captures some measurement `meas1` at different locations `locid` for two different teams `team` - I need to compute the similarity between the distribution of `meas1` values for each location across the two groups - `gp1` and `gp2`. For measuring the similarity I intend to use the `corr` function which gives the correlation coefficient between two distributions.

**table1**

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| locid |  make  |  meas1 |  team  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1111 |  make1 |      1 |  gp1   |
|  1111 |  make1 |      2 |  gp1   |
|  1111 |  make2 |      2 |  gp2   |
|  1111 |  make3 |      1 |  gp2   |
|  1112 |  make1 |      2 |  gp1   |
|  1112 |  make2 |      2 |  gp2   |
|  1112 |  make3 |      2 |  gp2   |
|  1113 |  make1 |      2 |  gp1   |
|  1113 |  make2 |      2 |  gp2   |
|  1113 |  make2 |      3 |  gp2   |
|  1113 |  make3 |      1 |  gp2   |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

My attempt

```
select locId,
    corr((select meas1 from table1 where team = 'gp1'), (select meas1 from table1 where team = 'gp2') ) as corr_meas1
    group by locId;
```

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/ACECNB15700)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to self join the table so that `meas1` of teams form comparable pairs. Something like

```
select t1.locId,
    corr(t1. meas1, t2.meas1)
    from table1 t1
    join table1 t2 on t1.team = 'gp1' and t2.team = 'gp1' and t1.locId =  t2.locId 
      and t1.make = t2.make 
    group by t1.locId;
```

Adjust join condition as needed.